# Can WatchKit WKInterfaceGroup be a Button?

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacegroup

(using iOS8.3, Xcode6.3, OSX10.10.3)

Hi, I wonder if a WatchKit WKInterfaceGroup can be a Button ??

In my watchkit-application, I would like to maximize the touch-surface for a particular action.

I know that one can place one or more buttons in a goup (next to other things like labels, images etc). Having such a WKInterfaceGroup (called group) with small items in it - I thought of placing several buttons, all filling out the empty space between the groups container.

But by placing several buttons close to each other in the group, even if they all reference to the very same action, I realised that touching two buttons by the user's finger in the group would not lead me to the desired surface-increase.

The problem is, the user-finger touches more than one button at once and even tough, I gave all the buttons in the group, as just mentioned, the very same action behind, the action does not get fired off.

The solution might be, if possible, to define the entire group as a button. How would that work ?? (...maybe accessibility traits could help ?? or other....???). Or can you somehow overlay a button on to a group ???

Any idea appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `WKInterfaceButton`, change its content type to "group" in the attributes inspector in IB and fill it with whatever content you need.

Comment: Wow - I did not come up with the vice-versa-solution :) Thank you for the hint that a Button can contain a group (with labels, images etc.). I always was looking for the opposite (i.e. a group that can be defined as a Button). Sometimes it is that simple !! :)